# DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-9_1_0'

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, dll

I explain my situation.

I'm working on a Unity project since february 2022, I installed every Firebase package I needed (Auth, Database and Storage).
It's a game ONLY for Standalone target (not at all Android), everything work perfectly on my computer, and as it's a multiplayer game, I dropped my game to my friends to play together.

The problem is that one of my friend got an error when he tried to start the game. (I dropped the game with developpement build)

Here is the log :

```
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/33679/Desktop/dossiers/Jeu/Tiles II Mono/Tiles II_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/libFirebaseCppApp-9_1_0
DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-9_1_0 assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil(Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate)
  at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x000ef] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init(intptr)
  at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE..cctor () [0x00000] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.AppUtil.SetLogFunction (Firebase.LogUtil+LogMessageDelegate arg0) [0x00001] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..ctor () [0x0000f] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..cctor () [0x00011] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.LogUtil' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.FirebaseApp..cctor () [0x0004b] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.FirebaseApp' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.get_DefaultInstance () [0x00001] in <8477f86ebdec4272996598d09d23cfc3>:0 
  at AuthentificationHandler+<Coroutine_ConnectToFireBase>d__21.MoveNext () [0x0004a] in C:\Users\imgog\OneDrive\Bureau\Tiles II Project\Assets\Assets\Scripts\AuthentificationHandler.cs:272 
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00020] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\Scripting\Coroutines.cs:17 
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged2(MonoBehaviour, IEnumerator)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\Scripting\MonoBehaviour.bindings.cs:91)
AuthentificationHandler:ConnectToFireBase() (at C:\Users\imgog\OneDrive\Bureau\Tiles II Project\Assets\Assets\Scripts\AuthentificationHandler.cs:267)
MenuManager:Start() (at C:\Users\imgog\OneDrive\Bureau\Tiles II Project\Assets\Assets\Scripts\MenuManager.cs:59)

(Filename: C:/Users/imgog/OneDrive/Bureau/Tiles II Project/Assets/Assets/Scripts/AuthentificationHandler.cs Line: 267)

Set menu to index 0 named Loading
DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-9_1_0 assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil(Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate)
  at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x000ef] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init(intptr)
  at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE..cctor () [0x00000] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.AppUtil.SetLogFunction (Firebase.LogUtil+LogMessageDelegate arg0) [0x00001] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..ctor () [0x0000f] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..cctor () [0x00011] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.LogUtil' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.FirebaseApp..cctor () [0x0004b] in <cb1e7f4be02d435283e0612f95918e31>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.FirebaseApp' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.get_DefaultInstance () [0x00001] in <353483bf71234bc2b81c7712bb95dbaf>:0 
  at DataBaseHandler.Start () [0x00001] in C:\Users\imgog\OneDrive\Bureau\Tiles II Project\Assets\Assets\Scripts\DataBaseHandler.cs:41
```

I tried every solution by typing my request :

- Neither IL2CPP or Mono works.
- My friend has a Windows 64-bit device, I tried to send him 32-bit and 64-bit (IL2CPP and Mono), no one works.
- I putted some code which call a Firebase function before calling FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependencies(), after fixed that, the result is the same.
- I reimported all firebase packages (9.1.0 to 9.2.0). Nothing changed.

The worst part is that it works on my computer, on any other buddy's computer since February, and it's only on a totally random computer that it happens.

I would like to know how to fix this problem, especially what information I need to have about my friend's computer to fix this problem (knowing that I thought it was maybe because it didn't have the same architecture, which I tested on my part (I have a 64-bit and I tested my game compiled in 32-bit) and I had the same error as my friend).

Comment: Use https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies on that DLL on your friend's computer to figure why it cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try to reimport your firebase unitypackage

Answer (score 0):

I had this error for ANDROID and I fix it (I haven't tested it for iOS jet) DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-11_2_0 assembly:
It was actually very simple for me.

1. The Firebase and ExternalDependencyManager folders must be located in the Asset folder; you should not move them elsewhere.
2. Delete the Firebase and ExternalDependencyManager folders and then install each Firebase SDK asset you need.
3. Run Force resolve.
   [Android force resolve location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI8nO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Follow these steps -

1. Remove Firebase and external library folder from Assets.
2. Import again.
3. Run Unity, you will get popup of unidentified developer. And you have only two options in popup so you can select to move to bin.
4. Then in system preferences -> Allow bundle.
5. Open Bin and drag and drop deleted bundle which is "FirebaseCppApp-11_6_0.bundle" to Assets in Unity.
6. Make sure settings allow that bundle.
7. Run Unity and it will run project successfully!